# Android: Combination of AsyncTask and get()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, get

In my android app, I have to load the data on first run through online server. But after splash screen, the loading bar should be displayed with black background. But when I am doing, it shows the content behind the progress bar. what i want is just to display the progress bar (with black background) until the data gets downloaded.

Here is my code of mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    task myTask = new task();

    myTask.execute();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //other code
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

class task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(progressDialog!=null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Well, while copy-pasting some of the brackets may be gone wrong.

But be assured the code is running fine, The problem comes that background is loaded alongwith the loading screen. I got to know about get() method to stop the process being loaded. But this also stopped the view of loading bar.

Please help. Or any alternative way suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `setContentView()` from `onCreate()` and place it in `onPostExecute()` at the end.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it though.. But I think I messed up my drawables that's giving me an error while moving setcontentview to postexecute. Just re-made a new app n tested. works perfect. Gonna make the whole clean project again! :)